# Nature of MetaFont Output: raster or vector?

Tags: fonts, metafont

I read that MetaFont defines vector fonts. Elsewhere it says it produces raster output. What kind of font does MetaFont really produce?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fonts with MetaFont are similar to TrueType and Type1 (and OpenType) fonts. Fonts are described in terms of curves and lines but the display is always in pixels, because most used output formats are based on pixels (like screen, laser printer,...). The difference is (among many others, such as hinting) that the place where rasterization happens is different. MetaFont converts these vector fonts into bitmaps right away (the pk-files) and the other font formats are turned into pixels at the system level (like the operating system or the pdf viewer). If the bitmaps are not optimized for the current output device (which is really hard to do nowadays), the output gets ugly. This is why we only use these "vector fonts" today. The rasterizer knows its output device.

Comment: Actually, the output usually looks pretty decent; with the one exception of which I am aware being Adobe [Acrobat] Reader, as long as the fonts have a decent resolution. (Though admittedly I haven't tried printing a document with 300 DPI fonts on a 360 DPI printer. Yet. But anyway, most on-screen renderers seem to do okay, and would in fact provide far uglier output if the fonts *were* rendered by metafont for the display resolution.)

Comment: What about sub pixel rendering, hinting etc? Can this be done with bitmaps?

Comment: @SamB Pixel fonts in Adobe Reader used to look hideous, but these days I thought it did an okay job. I don't agree that a MetaFont bitmap at screen resolution would look appreciably worse than a rasterised vector font, but it depends on what you're used to (Mac OS X's font anti-aliasing is far different than Windows' ClearType).

Comment: @Patrick Not with bitmaps, but with MetaFont (a) no to sub-pixel, but (b) yes to "hinting", although the process would be different — you can add resolution-dependent instructions to the output process to improve low-res display, which would be equivalent to what hinting tries to achieve on-screen.

Comment: @Will: This was based on having tried Yap with very low DPI (72?) metafont "mode" ... it really wasn't pretty, even allowing for the slightly-different DPI being assumed for display. (Of course, this might be related to my being accustomed to the anti-aliased results of the more usual "have metafont render at 300 DPI and resample down to the pretended display res", but I really doubt the Computer Modern family was "hinted" to the same degree as Times New Roman and friends -- or that metafont can even allow that kind of pixel-pushing tweakage.)

Comment: @Will: Though I'd be happy to be proven wrong re: support for pixel-pushing in metafont.

Comment: @SamB you're right — CM was never designed for such low resolution. But someone *could*, if they had the energy, design a high-quality bitmap screen font for a range of sizes in MetaFont. But practically it's better to do things in outlines these days; see MetaType1 for a modern alternative.

Comment: @Will: yeah, it's kind of pointless given mf's lack of (a) Unicode support, (b) OS integration, and (c) anti-aliasing/cleartype. Though maybe (b) isn't really as important as it seems; Type1 outlines don't seem to fit in very well on (at least) Windows XP anyway.

Comment: The produced fonts (when displayed) are always bitmaps, the sources are always vector fonts (type 3 is different from what I've heard, they can contain pretty much any postscript code, I think). The only difference is the time they are being rasterized. I don't know the definition of outline fonts nor of stroke fonts. I'd consider metafont fonts bitmap fonts and the other ones vector fonts. But only in a practical sense, not in a technical sense.

Comment: I was just reading "I doubt [...] that metafont can even allow that kind of pixel-pushing tweakage" and thinking "wow how wrong is this guy; metafont *can* do anything". Then, of course, I noticed *I* wrote that. Now I kind of wish we could ship metafonts around in our PDF/PostScript, and have them rendered using an appropriate mode for the actual printer ...

Comment: Also, I suspect optimizing Metafont's output for a given output device is about as difficult as it always has been; I suspect the actual reasons this don't happen much anymore are more along the lines of: (1) Printers are cheaper to operate now, and no longer seen as being particularly arcane, so it is harder to justify having such skilled minders for them as in the early days of TeX. (2) Printers are networked now, and people usually run the output drivers locally, so there's no single point of configuration anyway. (3) Non-tuned output (pk or Type1) usually gives okay results nowadays. ...

Comment: ... Last but not least, (4) when producing a PostScript or PDF file, one often doesn't even *know* what the output device will be, which makes it pretty damn hard to tune the output for that device; combined with Adobe Reader's bad track record for rendering Type3 bitmap fonts, this makes Type1 or even TTF fonts a highly attractive alternative -- you already can't have Metafont's device-specific tuning, so unless you wanted to make your own font variant, you aren't really losing much by picking a less-flexible alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Metafont outputs raster fonts (bitmaps, in other words). It never deals with vector shapes. Yes, the curves are defined programmatically, but the moment Metafont encounters the instruction like "draw some curve/path" it discretizes the path. This actually allows some features of Metafont (like erasing, pens) to be implemented in a more or less straightforward way.